# UIView alway show full screen in simulator although setting width and height to 320 x 320 px by Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I try to show UIView of HomeViewController as modal of TabBarViewController.

I want UIView display over TabBar and there 's TabBar at bottom of screen.

Although, setting  setting  UIView of HomeController 's width and height to 320 x 320 px does not prevent the view to show full screen.
It cover UITabBar and I can not see UITabBar at button of screen when application start up.

This is my code.

//in TabBarWithHomeAppDelegate.m - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method

```
homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]
                      initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];


self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;


[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

self.tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);

[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:homeViewController animated:NO];

return YES;
```

[image]

Interface builder short screen

in Simulator

[image]

and this is my source code

[link to download source code](http://codesanook.com/code/TabBarWithHome.zip)

Any suggestion is valuable.

Thanks,

Comment: Modal views are always presented in full screen on the iPhone. You need to use a UIView as a subview of your current UIViewControllers view.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a modal view with a tab bar as you are doing in the current context. Instead, let the `HomeViewController` view be full screen. To display the tab bar, go to Simulated Metrics in Interface Builder & select Tab Bar for the bottom bar. That way, your view will not be modal & will be truncated to the space between the navigation bar & the tab bar.